# Calendar with Saturday & Sunday disabled

Tags: android, calendar, datepickerdialog

I used **DatePickerDialog** to show the calendar so that the user can select the date.my requirement is that Saturday and Sunday must be disabled in the calendar . how can I do this? Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can code like this:

```
if (choosenDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 
                    Calendar.SUNDAY ||
choosenDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 
                    Calendar.SATURNDAY||
                    now.compareTo(choosenDate) < 0) {
                    dateTextView.setTextColor(
                        Color.parseColor("#ff0000")
                    );
                    ((Button) dialog.getButton(
                    AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE))
                        .setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    dateTextView.setTextColor(
                        Color.parseColor("#000000")
                    );
                    ((Button) dialog.getButton(
                    AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE))
                        .setEnabled(true);
                }
```

Comment: hi thanks for the answer. whether i can customize the datepickerdialog as i needed.

Comment: You should define a class `DatePickerFragment`. I can suggest you a site where you can find the to customize DatePickerDialog. Here is this:
http://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/08/android-datepickerdialog-title.html